How to express "X-Y%" or "about Z%" as a Dirichlet prior
I'm working on a problem where we are getting the estimate of a mass fraction of an object from a source. The source provides mass fraction ranges or sometimes point estimates. For example, $m_1$ is between 80-90%, $m_2$ is between 10-20%, $m_3$ is 2.4%, and $m_4$ < 1%.
It seems appropriate to model the distribution of mass fractions as a categorical distribution since $\sum_i m_i = 1$. A Dirichlet distribution would be a natural choice for expressing the prior information on these mass fractions $m_i$ since the Dirichlet is the conjugate prior of a categorical distribution. What would be the most appropriate way to express the uncertainty range of "X-Y%" or point estimates like "Z%" in a Dirichlet distribution?

A Dirichlet prior is for a vector of such proportions. If you only have one ("about Z%", say), then it would be the simple case of a beta prior; if you specified (say) the mean (Z) and standard deviation (how near to Z "about" is), then you have your prior, since those two determine the parameters (it doesn't have to be mean and standard deviation, of course, pick what you like). Do mean that you have a vector of such pieces of information?

@Glen_b thanks for the response. Agree that the dirichlet prior can express the "Z%" parts of the prior, but how would you express the "X-Y%" part?

Its essentially the same issue as specifying what "about" means. How much probability does that interval cover?
